# SQL Server DATEADD null value error behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am seeing something weird happen with DATEADD in sqlserver:

```
declare @buffdays smallint = null
declare @scheduledDeleteTime datetime2 = null
declare @FileNotExistOnDisk bit = 0
if (@FileNotExistOnDisk = 0)
begin
    set @scheduledDeleteTime = DATEADD(day, @buffdays, GETDATE())   
end
select @scheduledDeleteTime
```

returns `NULL`

However, this:

```
declare @buffdays smallint = null
declare @scheduledDeleteTime datetime2 = null
declare @FileNotExistOnDisk bit = 0
if (@FileNotExistOnDisk = 0)
begin
    set @scheduledDeleteTime = DATEADD(day, null, GETDATE())   
end
select @scheduledDeleteTime
```

returns:
`Argument data type NULL is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.`

Can someone please explain why I am seeing this difference in behavior between the two? The second results makes sense to me, but I cannot understand why the first is not throwing an error...

Comment: _"number
An expression that can resolve to an int that DATEADD adds to a datepart of date. DATEADD accepts user-defined variable values for number..."_ So it's about the syntax, in the first place you pass a variable not a NULL, thus it works, and the second not, it can be also an expression as `SELECT DATEADD(Day, CAST(NULL AS INT), GETDATE())`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: `So it's about the syntax` - a weird syntax though, it means it has different kinds of NULL, from user perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd query is caught by the platforms exception handling.

The 1st is passing the argument without catching exception.  `NULL` combined with anything is `NULL`.